# Image Rotation using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, image-rotation

PLEASE DO NOT RECOMMEND JQUERY - I AM DOING THIS EXERCISE FOR LEARNING PURPOSES.

I have implemented a JavaScript, which rotates images (_elementSlideChange) on a timer, using a set interval of 10 seconds. Also I have added a slide functionality to this, which is 7 milliseconds (_slideImage).

The image rotates automatically every 10 seconds on page load, and I have also provided next and previous buttons, which allow the user to change the images manually.

```
_elementSlideChange: function () {
  var myString;
  var myText;
  for (var i = 0; i < this._imgArray.length; i++) {
    var imageArr = "url(" + this._imgArray[i].src + ")";
    var imageBg = this._imageHolder.style.background + "";
    if (imageArr == imageBg) {
      if (i == (this._imgArray.length - 1)) {
        myString = "url(" + this._imgArray[0].src + ")";
        myText = this._infoArray[0];
      } else {
        myString = "url(" + this._imgArray[(i + 1)].src + ")";
        myText = this._infoArray[i + 1];
      }
    }
  }
  this._imageNextSlide.style.background = myString;
  this._imageNextSlide.style.background);
  this._infoElement.innerHTML = myText;
  this._myTimer = setInterval(MyProject.Utils.createDelegate(this._slideImage, this),  7);
},
_slideImage: function () {
  if (parseInt(this._imageHolder.style.width) >= 0 && parseInt(this._imageNextSlide.style.width) <= 450) {
    this._imageHolder.style.backgroundPosition = "right";
    this._imageHolder.style.width = (parseInt(this._imageHolder.style.width) - 1) + 'px';
    console.log(this._imageNextSlide.style.background);
    this._imageNextSlide.style.width = (parseInt(this._imageNextSlide.style.width) + 1) + 'px';
  } else {
    console.log("reached 0px");
    if (parseInt(this._imageHolder.style.width) == 0) {
      this._imageHolder.style.background = this._imageNextSlide.style.background;
      this._imageHolder.style.width = 450 + 'px';
      this._imageHolder === this._imageNextSlide;
      this._imageHolder.className = "orginalImage";
      this._imageNextSlide.style.width = 0 + "px";
      this._imageNextSlide = this._dummyImageNextSlide;
      this._imagesElement.appendChild(this._imageHolder);
      this._imagesElement.appendChild(this._imageNextSlide);
      clearInterval(this._myTimer);
    }
    clearInterval(this._myTimer);
    clearInterval(this._elementSlideChange);
  }
}
```

So when the user clicks on the Next arrow button, the event listener for "click" is triggered. This creates a div for the current image on display, and creates a new div, which will contain the next image. The image slide and rotation works correctly (whether it's `onLoad` or `onClick`). The issue I have is if I click the Next button, while the new div image is sliding into position, it causes it to run into an infinite loop, so the same div with the image to be displayed keeps sliding in, and the more you click the Next button, the faster the image starts to rotate.

I have tried putting a clear interval for the image rotation and slider, but I do understand my code is wrong, which causes the infinite loop of the sliding image. And I know I am close to finishing the functionality.

Can anyone please advise where I could be going wrong? Or should I try to implement the sliding DIV in another way?

Once again please don't recommend jQuery.

And thank you for your help in advance.

Kush

Comment: Did you even read the first line of what i wrote???

Comment: Yes, but somebody had to make the obligatory jQuery plug. It's part of unwritten SO rules. Now we can move on with actually answering the question.

Comment: Looks like someone forgot their sense of humor home.

Comment: Can you put a demo on jsfiddle or something ? It is kinda hard to understand the effect and the problem you are having

Comment: Could you make a JS fiddle of your exercise so we could have a look at the live code?

Comment: Pete, i have tried that but it doesnt prevent the Loop, as i believe the issue is to do with the this._slideImage, As the current image is in this._imageHolder
and this._imageNextSlide carries the next image which will slide to the left and when reaching 0 px left of DIV, it becomes the current Image (this._imageHolder

Comment: Okay give me few minutes ill put it on jsFiddle

Comment: For starters here are some red flags I see: there are only 2 functions in that whole big block of code. You repeat the same types of statements many times with only small parts changing. Rewrite that stuff! You will find that as you break into parts and name things and test smaller pieces that you suddenly start solving problems. And don't forget js code tools like http://jshint.org.

Comment: P.S. Have you considered using jQuery? It would be much easier. :D

Comment: yes i know its easier but don't want to be lazy :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, I did re-write the entire code, where I had a next and previous button event listener.

```
myProject.Utils.addHandler(this._nextImageElement, "click", myProject.Utils.createDelegate(this._changeImage, this));
```

Both the buttons will call the same function :

```
_changeImage: function (e)
```

In this function I check to see if the function is Transition (changing images),
I declare a boolean  `var forward = e.target == this._nextImageElement;`

Then check to see the current index if forward ? Add 1 else minus 1

```
this._currentImageIndex += forward ? 1 : -1;
```

If its at the end of the Array and forward is true, assign the this._currentImageIndex to reset to 0 or Array.length – 1 if it’s in reverse

Then call another function which gives the ‘div’ a sliding effect. In this case call it `this._transitionImage(forward);`

In this function, set the this._inTranstion to true. (Because the div’s are sliding in this case).

**The following code solved the issue i was having.**

```
this._slideImageElement.style.backgroundImage = "url(\"" + this._imgArray[this._currentImageIndex].src + "\")";

this._slideImageElement.style.backgroundPosition = forward ? "left" : "right";        
this._slideImageElement.style.left = forward ? "auto" : "0px";
this._slideImageElement.style.right = forward ? "0px" : "auto";
```

The above code is very important as the object is to place the “sliding in div” Left or Right of the current Visible “div” to the user, and this is mainly dependent on if the forward variable is true or false.

```
var i = 0;
```

Then start the transition by

```
setInterval( function() {
    this._currentImageElement.style.backgroundPosition = (forward ? -1 : 1) * (i + 1) + "px";
       this._slideImageElement.style.width = (i + 1) + "px";
```

Notice the forward will determine if the bgPosition will go to the left if its forward as we multiple by -1 or +1,
So for example
If the user clicks NEXT BUTTON,
Forward = true
So the first thing we do is set the

```
this._slideImageElement.style.backgroundPosition = "left"
```

Then

```
this._slideImageElement.style.left = "auto"
this._slideImageElement.style.right = "0px"
```

***This means when the sliding image moves in its background position is LEFT but the div is placed on the RIGHT to 0px;***
then  t`his._currentImageElement.style.backgroundPosition = -1 * (i + 1)` 
*Which moves the position of the currentImageElement to the left by 1px*,

Increase the **width of the slideImage** which in this case is *right* of the current div, 
and as the *current div moves to the left the sliding image starts to appear from the right*. (By default set the width of slideImageElement to 0px so the div exists but isn’t visible to the user). *This gives it the slide effect of moving forward new image coming from the right.*

```
this._slideImageElement.style.width = (i + 1) + "px";
```

then declare it to stop when it it’s the image width. In this case it will be 500px.
**if ((i = i + 2) == 500) {**
    In this if statement reset the currentImageElement background and the background position “right” or “left” don’t really matter as long it has been reset.

Clear the interval 
Set the transition to false again
Then call a setTimeout for the function changeImage, which will continue until the slide is completed.

**The following shows the reset code as this is very important to prevent repeating the same image (This solved my entire issue)**

```
// set the current image to the "new" current image and reset it's background position
this._currentImageElement.style.backgroundImage = "url(\"" + this._imgArray[this._currentImageIndex].src + "\")";
this._currentImageElement.style.backgroundPosition = "right";

// reset the slide image width
this._slideImageElement.style.width = "0px";

// clear the transition interval and mark as not in transition
clearInterval(this._transitionInterval);
                this._inTransition = false;

// setup the next image timer
this._nextImageTimeout = setTimeout(myProject.Utils.createDelegate(this._changeImage, this), 2500);
```

}

I have provided a thorough detail because then it easier to understand the logic of the problem, and even if your not having the same issue, this may help you fingure out any problem.

I couldn't provide a JSfiddle, as i have created my CSS using Javascript, there are different ways of doing this, but i wanted to understand the logic behind the forward and reverse, and having a timer which continuously goes forward.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to cancel the animation on the slide (perhaps have it fade out while the next slide animates in, cancel its animation abruptly or let it finish and ignore the button click)

What I usually do, personally, is check for the animated state (yes, I use jquery, but you should be able to test the CSS or positioning values you are using to animate in the same way) you could even add an "active" class or data type during animation to make testing easier. Global flags work, too. If there is animation, ignore the button. (For my work... Depends on your intention)

Like I said, the problem may be with button behaviour not with the animation routine. It would be useful to see how you are calling this from the button click, and what your intended results are going to be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it turns out it was the fact i wasn't resetting the position of the Div, and i needed to include
In the setInterval function i included,
clearInterval(this._transitionInterval);

This made sure that the change of the image was completed, so if the user does click on the button again it will make sure until the function hasn't completed it will continue finishing, then perform the intended action, whether its forward or reverse. 
I have got it to work, and will be posting my answer, thanks for your help :).

Answer (score -1):

How about CSS3 transitions?

```
transition: all 1s ease 0.5s;
```

[Simple example on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GvJ9v/).

This takes care of the animation, so you just need to set the intended destination using JavaScript, i.e.

```
this.style.left = '100px';
```

Or

```
this.style.top = '30px';
```

And CSS3 transitions will smoothly slide the element.

Cross Browser Note!

The `transition` property may need a vendor prefix for some browsers, I am using the latest production Firefox and you don't need `-moz` for that. Same goes for Opera, no '-o' required. Internet Exporer 10 needs no prefix. You may need to use `-webkit` for Safari / Chrome, but test without first.

Comment: CSS3 isn't what i am performing this exercise on, its mainly to learn Javascript without the use of Libraries, hence i didnt want to use jQuery. But thanks i shall keep that in mind for the future.